# AWS ElasticBeanstalk - Auto scaled instance can't see environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using Elastic beanstalk autoscaling for an application, recently added a new SQS queue as an environment variable.

I can see the variable using  `eb printenv *my-env* | grep "SQS"`:

```
 SQS_QUEUE = https://sqs.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx
```

When I SSH to a newly created instance I can't see that config `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment --output YAML | grep "SQS"`

If I make a code change and deploy then the instance gets the config - this isn't a practical solution when the scaling goes up / down multiple times a day.

I'm using a custom AMI but I can't find any documentation on AWS around environment variables - adding new ones should just work..!?

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0):

Please double check. I think `-output YAML` is incorrect. The queue should be accessible through:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -key SQS_QUEUE
```

Comment: -output is either YAML / JSON and it outputs the entire list, which I was filtering with grep

If I do as you suggest. - sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k SQS_QUEUE it is still empty on newly auto-scaled boxes until a new deployment occurs.

Comment: @user13177128 Is this EB platform based on Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: This is Amazon Linux 1, I'm able to test it on Amazon Linux 2 so I'll see if it behaves the same